# django session cookie when using DNS, and cookies in general

Tags: django, session, cookies, web, prefix

I have a website that requires login. I use django db-based session engine. If user has an active session, he will be logged-in automatically, and will not be required to login again.
I've noticed a problem when using my website DNS address, two sessions are opened if users browse with or without www prefix.

For example, if user login in the address www.mysite.com, and then he will change the address to just mysite.com, he will be required to login again, despite the fact that he technically  has an open session, and a session cookie in his browser.

I assume that it is a cookie issue alone, and not a django specific thing. I guess the browser won't serve the session cookie, since it consider mysite.com and www.mysite.com to be different addresses.
But still, is there anything I can do in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem than you, and to solve it I just added this line in my settings.py :

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.yourDomain.com'
```

The cookie will work for all subdomains of yourDomain.com (including www.yourDomain.com)